# Determine if a view is inside of a Popover view

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

We have common views that we use in our application in many locations inside of `UINavigationControllers`. Occasionally the `UINavigationController`s are inside of popover views. Now the views we put into the nav controllers modify their navigation controller's toolbar buttons and, in some cases, use custom buttons that we've created. We need to be able to figure out from the `UIViewcontroller` itself if the view is inside of a popoverview so we can display the correctly colored buttons.

We can easily get the Navigation controller reference from the UIViewController, using `UIViewController.navigationController`, but there doesn't seem to be anything for finding a `UIPopoverController`.

Does anyone have any good ideas for how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was recently looking for a way to determine wether or not a view was being displayed in a popover. This is what I came up with:

```
    UIView *v=theViewInQuestion;        
    for (;v.superview != nil; v=v.superview) {
        if (!strcmp(object_getClassName(v), "UIPopoverView")) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n\nIM IN A POPOVER!\n\n\n\n");
        }
```

Basically you climb the view's superview tree looking to see if any of its superviews is a UIPopoverView. The one caveat here is that the class UIPopoverView is an undocumented private class. I'm relying on the fact that the class name won't change in the future. YMMV.

In your case:

```
theViewInQuestion =  theViewControllerInQuestion.view;
```

I'd be interested to see if anyone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like a viable solution, thanks for the feedback! I ended up doing something slightly different and more specific to my app to figure this out, but it looks like this would work as well so I'm going to mark it as the correct answer! Thanks!

Comment: The problem with this is it only finds you the UIPopoverView... How do you turn that into the controller?

Comment: This is a good solution.  `isKindOfClass` is preferable to a string comparison. I have implemented it in a UIView category as "isInPopover" in my refactoring library, https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils

Comment: It is AppStore-safe, but for iOS 5.1 and 6 the classname is now _UIPopoverView.

Comment: hard coding an undocumented class name in your code == bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

As Artem said we have `UIPopoverPresentationController` since **iOS8**. To determine if view is in popover you can use its `.arrowDirection` property for example.

Check it in `viewWillApear()` of presented view controller:

```
// get it from parent NavigationController
UIPopoverPresentationController* popoverPresentationVC = self.parentViewController.popoverPresentationController; 
if (UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown > popoverPresentationVC.arrowDirection) {
// presented as popover
} else {
// presented as modal view controller (on iPhone)
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best solution: unlike other proposals, this works correctly on constrained devices when a VC is presented as a popover. On small screens the VC will actually appear full-screen rather than in a popover - this is detected correctly.

Comment: simply brilliant. checking for existence of `popoverPresentationController` is not enough. Additionally checking for the arrow direction did the trick. Moreover, this could be further simplified by `if self.popoverPresentationController?.arrowDirection == .unknown {...`

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution; define a protocol (e.g. PopoverSensitiveController) that has only one method:

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

@protocol PopoverSensitiveController 
-(void) setIsInPopover:(BOOL) inPopover;
@end
```

A view controller that wants to know if it is in a popover then defines a property isInPopover; for example:

```
#import 
#import "PopoverSensitiveController.h"

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Interface
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController  {
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Properties
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isInPopover;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Instance Methods
...other stuff...
@end
```

Finally, in the splitView delegate (the assumption is that your app uses a split view controller):

```
#import "MySplitViewControllerDelegate.h"
#import "SubstitutableDetailViewController.h"
#import "PopoverSensitiveController.h"

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Implementation
@implementation MySplitViewControllerDelegate

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol methods
-(void) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *) splitViewController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *) aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *) pc {

  // Keep references to the popover controller and the popover button, and tell the detail view controller to show the button
  popoverController = [pc retain];
  popoverButtonItem = [barButtonItem retain];
  if ([[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] respondsToSelector:@selector(showRootPopoverButtonItem:)]) {
      UIViewController *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
      [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:barButtonItem];
  }
  if ([[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] respondsToSelector:@selector(showRootPopoverButtonItem:)]) {
      UIViewController *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
      [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:barButtonItem];
  }

  // If the view controller wants to know, tell it that it is a popover
  if ([aViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsInPopover:)]) {
    [(id) aViewController setIsInPopover:YES];
  }

  // Make sure the proper view controller is in the popover controller and the size is as requested
  popoverController.contentViewController = aViewController;
  popoverController.popoverContentSize = aViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover;

}

-(void) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *) splitViewController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *) aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItem {

  // Tell the detail view controller to hide the button.
  if ([[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] respondsToSelector:@selector(invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:)]) {
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    [detailViewController invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:barButtonItem];
  }

  // If the view controller wants to know, tell it that it is not in a popover anymore
  if ([aViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsInPopover:)]) {
    [(id) aViewController setIsInPopover:NO];
  }

  // Now clear out everything
  [popoverController release];
  popoverController = nil;
  [popoverButtonItem release];
  popoverButtonItem = nil;

}

-(void) setPopoverButtonForSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *) splitViewController {

  // Deal with the popover button
  UIViewController *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
  [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:popoverButtonItem];

  // If the view controller wants to know, tell it that it is a popover (initialize the controller properly)
  if ([[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsInPopover:)]) {
    [(id) [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setIsInPopover:YES];
  }

}
```

Then where ever in the view controller you want to know if you are in a popover, simply use the isInPopover property.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS8 you can use popoverPresentationController property of UIViewController to check if it is contained in a popover presentation controller. From documentation, it returns: "The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a popover presentation controller. (read-only)"

Comment: This seems to only return a valid object (i.e. non-nil) after the view of the view controller has been displayed. i.e. this returned `nil` for me from `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: In iOS 9, this works for me in viewWillAppear, but not in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3):

Modification of the accepted answer for iOS5.1 and newer:

```
for (UIView *v = self.view; v.superview != nil; v=v.superview) { 

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"_UIPopoverView") class]]) {

        NSLog(@"\n\n\nIM IN A POPOVER!\n\n\n\n");

    }
}
```

** NOTE **

See comments about the reliability of this code.

Comment: Note that if your view is in a UINavigationController, you'll need `UIView *v = self.navigationController.view` (because `self.view.superview` is `nil` in a navigation controller.)

Comment: I am not sure why this is supposed to be good? This way of doing it _already_ broke from iOS 4.x -> 5.1. It'll break again in the future. Maybe this is good if you're looking for perpetual employment but it's not good code.

Comment: I agree. I simply posted as reference for the accepted answer (maybe I shouldn't have? I'll edit my response with a note). My gut is that there was probably a reason to change it, and if so it's likely to be changed again. I ended up using JScarry's contentSize suggestion. I'm betting that as long as the exact size is fractional, it's less likely to break underneath you.

Comment: Although seconds after writing the above I'm thinking that with auto layout it may be risky since the system is dictating size based on constraints.

Answer (score 2):

My approach for this: (available with iOS 8 or greater)

```
- (BOOL)isContainedInPopover
{
    UIPopoverPresentationController* popoverPresentationVC = self.parentViewController.popoverPresentationController;
    return (popoverPresentationVC != nil);
}
```

Parent view controller will be the navigation controller which if inside a popover, will have a non-nil `popoverPresentationController` property.

Answer (score 1):

By working with SpareTime's code I came to this, which works as expected. Nice code, nice solution:

Using the standard UISplitViewController example.

```
/* MasterViewController.h */

#import "UIPopoverViewDelegate.h"

@interface masterViewController : UITableViewController <UIPopoverViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isInPopover;
@end
```

---

```
/* MasterViewController.m */

#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize isInPopover = _isInPopover;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.isInPopover)
    {
        // Code for appearing in popover
    }
    else
    {
        // Code for not appearing in popover
    }
}

@end
```

---

```
/* DetailViewController.h */

#import "UIPopoverViewDelegate.h"

@interface detailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

---

```
/* DetailViewController.m */

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation detailViewController

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{

    /* This method is called when transitioning to PORTRAIT orientation. */

    UIViewController *hiddenViewController = [(UINavigationController *)viewController childViewControllers].lastObject;

    if ([hiddenViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsInPopover:)])
        [(id <UIPopoverViewDelegate>)hiddenViewController setIsInPopover:YES];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{

    /* This method is called when transitioning to LANDSCAPE orientation. */

    UIViewController *shownViewController = [(UINavigationController *)viewController childViewControllers].lastObject;

    if ([shownViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsInPopover:)])
        [(id <UIPopoverViewDelegate>)shownViewController setIsInPopover:NO];
}

@end
```

---

```
/* UIPopoverViewDelegate.h */

@protocol UIPopoverViewDelegate
@required
-(void)setIsInPopover:(BOOL)inPopover;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In case that someone else is still looking for a solution i came up with one good enough for me.

Just override this method

```
func presentationController(_ controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {

    (controller.presentedViewController as? YourViewControler).isPopover = false

    return controller.presentedViewController
}
```

Here is an example of YourViewController

```
class AdvisorHomeFilterViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var isPopover = true
}
```

If it is popover it will not call 'viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle' method and it will stay true, in case it is not popover it will set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put up a button in the view if the view *wasn't* displayed in a popover. I know the width of the popover because I just set it. So i can test whether I'm on an iPad and if the width of the frame is the same as what I set.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(400, 500)];

NSInteger frameWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
//Let you go back to the game if on an iPod.
if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) && !(frameWidth == 400) ) { ---code to display a button --}
```

Comment: hacking the contentsize is a neat idea. why not set it to, say 400.1 and compare with that?

Comment: I’m not actually hacking the content size. I just set the size so that it is big enough to contain all of the elements that I need. If I set it to a non-integer width, then the edges won’t lie on a pixel boundary.

Answer (score 0):

All these **'Exact Classname Matching Approaches'** are very prone to fail and break at even the slightest changes Apple will make. Also doing one-char-vars and cryptic for-loops is not exactly a solution fitting to my style.

I use followingpiece of code:

```
- (BOOL) isInPopOver {
    UIView *currentView = self.view;
    while( currentView ) {
        NSString *classNameOfCurrentView = NSStringFromClass([currentView class]);
        NSLog( @"CLASS-DETECTED: %@", classNameOfCurrentView );
        NSString *searchString = @"UIPopoverView";
        if( [classNameOfCurrentView rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ) {
            return YES;
        }
        currentView = currentView.superview;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above seems a little bit complicated. I'm using a variable called `isInPopover` which I set to true if the view controller is presented in a popover. In the view controller in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` or in `viewWillDisappear` I set the boolean value to false. It does work and is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since `self.popoverPresentationController` is created lazily in most recent iOS versions, one should check for nil-ness of `self.popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController`, if not nil this would mean `self` is currently presented in a popover.

Comment: Got any source on this?

Comment: @zaitsman The answer is 4 years old, I don't know how accurate it is now. Last time I checked I think popoverPresentationController was only created if modalPresentationStyle was set to .popover. No source, just my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version (function can be added in `extension UIViewController`):

```
func isInPopover() -> Bool {
    guard UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad else { return false }

    var checkingVC: UIViewController? = self
    repeat {
        if checkingVC?.modalPresentationStyle == .popover {
            return true
        }
        checkingVC = checkingVC?.parent
    } while checkingVC != nil
    return false
}
```