# How to know if my UIViewController is being showed as a UIPopoverController

Tags: uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a UIViewController which I show sometimes as a UIViewController and some others like UIPopoverController, but I want them to show a different message depending if is showed as one or another, is there a line of code which helps me to know this?

something like:

```
if(self.popover) NSLog(@"this is a popover");
else NSLog(@"this is a viewcontroller");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191840/determine-if-a-view-is-inside-of-a-popover-view for discussion of several methods to do this.

Comment: I tried with a couple of them but none worked, I must say it is a popover inside of a navigation controller for displaying it's buttons as well